# nodejs keypair rsa module public key not working

Tags: node.js, encryption, rsa, public-key

i am using [Keypair module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keypair)

it is working fine created public and private key

My public key:

```
    -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAh1Z9MSYMkQq1K8HzU4PAGl9GfEoM6TyXseHs7zxv9URyNycL6RWLvHlZzZhj
oskNCdQ5M7oB3Uahv/i3JCLLpqFtNGZdQdbnagkdM4kYNyDaQ4XCuZSQi7PZRZ3S8puz69Un
aHwmKSK0rkm8tWfSAtFPoaDcZ+CdS62745brUmcZM2mkhUUJYmtdys9f3iTtkJ108b6691b0
wLOP85SsjnngUju2di8tFngAHhon+eSl3DpeX7ZwgGsPr+7oKYdkM9tGlaOxTtCkdfnvVK5U
Z7efhvo1eGf2QSvPCuZnzkLg0zubKPEVhJ2wxEFFXl0/OmyoITklgJKF+0TRKmGtzQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

i am using [Jsencrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt)

> using that public key not working.. data not encrypted

but **jsencrypt** generate public key is working fine. can you help me?

How to use my generate keypair RSA publickey in **jsencrypt**?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript RSA Encryption</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bin/jsencrypt.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Call this code when the page is done loading.
      $(function() {

        // Run a quick encryption/decryption when they click.
        $('#testme').click(function() {

          // Encrypt with the public key...
          var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
          encrypt.setPublicKey($('#pubkey').val());
          var encrypted = encrypt.encrypt($('#input').val());

          // Decrypt with the private key...
          var decrypt = new JSEncrypt();
          decrypt.setPrivateKey($('#privkey').val());
          var uncrypted = decrypt.decrypt(encrypted);

          // Now a simple check to see if the round-trip worked.
          if (uncrypted == $('#input').val()) {
            alert('It works!!!');
          }
          else {
            alert('Something went wrong....');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="privkey">Private Key</label><br/>
    <textarea id="privkey" rows="15" cols="65">-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----</textarea><br/>
    <label for="pubkey">Public Key</label><br/>
    <textarea id="pubkey" rows="15" cols="65">-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDlOJu6TyygqxfWT7eLtGDwajtN
FOb9I5XRb6khyfD1Yt3YiCgQWMNW649887VGJiGr/L5i2osbl8C9+WJTeucF+S76
xFxdU6jE0NQ+Z+zEdhUTooNRaY5nZiu5PgDB0ED/ZKBUSLKL7eibMxZtMlUDHjm4
gwQco1KRMDSmXSMkDwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----</textarea><br/>
    <label for="input">Text to encrypt:</label><br/>
    <textarea id="input" name="input" type="text" rows=4 cols=70>This is a test!</textarea><br/>
    <input id="testme" type="button" value="Test Me!!!" /><br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you using it? Please show some code.

Comment: can you please check jsencrypt?

Comment: https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt

Answer (score 0):

This key is PKCS#1 encoded, public key should be PKCS#8 encoded to work with JSEncrypt.

PKCS#8 is something like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIB.....
...
...QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And it can be retrieved from private key using openssl:

```
openssl rsa -in private_key_file -outform PEM -pubout -out public_key_pkcs8.pub
```